# Get the SAML Assertion from Identity Provider for other Service Provider

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

My front-end application "App1", acts as a SAML Service Provider (SP). ADFS is my Identity Provider (IdP).
App1 internally uses a "backend connection" to third party system say "App2".
Note that this "App2" is another SP to the same ADFS IdP.

When user logs on to App1 from the browser (via ADFS), the "backend" connection to the App2 should work seamlessly (in SSO manner).
My plan is to pass the SAML assertion to App2 through the backend call. I am expecting App2 will decrypt/verify this assertion and returns the connection.

My Question is - Is there any way I can get SAML Assertion in App1 for App2 from the common IdP they are using?

Comment: You want App2's SAML assertion to be available in App1? I'm not sure how you would do this. I don't think there's a way to get ADFS to do this. You would need a custom API between the two apps to pass the SAML assertion.

I'm not sure why you want to do this though. App1 and App2 will both SSO to ADFS which will return the appropriate SAML assertion to each. If there's information in the SAML assertion sent to App2 that's also required by App1 wouldn't you just configure the claim rules in ADFS for both relying parties to include this information?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SSO between App1 and App2 is mainly based on browser and cookies. User logs on to App1 from the browser. Requirement is to pull data from app2 via backend call (non-browser based). I can get the required information from ADFS by defining claim rules, however App2 will issue its own ticket (connection in this case) only after it verifies the entire assertion (signatures and other details). Any pointers?